# excluding bugs that findBugs finds

Tags: java, findbugs

When I'm using findBugs, I get list of bugs. Some of the bugs I fix and some of them are not errors I wish to fix.

How can I configure findBugs to ignore these errors the next time I run it on my code?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Filter files](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is a good response about [SuppressWarnings](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/annotations/SuppressWarnings.html) answered in another question:
[When using Eclipse with FindBugs can you mark a bug as not a bug and have it removed from the bug list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249536/when-using-eclipse-with-findbugs-can-you-mark-a-bug-as-not-a-bug-and-have-it-rem)